# Vector won't display all inforamtion about an object in command line

Tags: java, vector, tostring

The output I though would come up:

> Length: XX Width: XX Title: XX Price: XX

The output I actually got:

> Title: XX Price: XX

***Why the program omitted ClassA's toString?***

**Main:**

```
case 'c':
                if(!theList.isEmpty()){
                for (int i = 0; i < theList.size(); i++)
                    System.out.println(theList.elementAt(i).toString());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("The list is empty!");
                }
                break;
```

**ClassA's toString():**

```
   @Override
public String toString(){
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    result.append("Length: ").append(this.getLength()).append('\n');
    result.append("Width: ").append(this.getWidth()).append('\n');
    return result.toString();
}
```

**ClassB's, that extends ClassA, toString():**

```
   @Override
public String toString(){
    super.toString();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    result.append("Title: ").append(this.getTitle()).append('\n');
    result.append("Price: ").append(this.getPrice()).append('\n');
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to use a [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead of a `Vector`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple. You only called A's `toString` method, but didn't use the return value at all.

Apart from that, I would write the `toString` method as follows:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return //
    "Length: " + getLength() + '\n' + //
    "Width: " + getWidth() + '\n';
}
```

The code is shorter, easier to read and compiles to equivalent bytecode as your current code. Same for B's `toString`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return super.toString() + //
    "Title: " + getTitle() + '\n' + //
    "Price: " + getPrice() + '\n';
}
```